# Managed Source Control Hosting and Continuous Integration with CVSDude and CruiseControl.net

Tags: svn, version-control, build-process, cruisecontrol.net

For my own project at home, I'm using the rather excellent managed subversion hosting from [CVSDude](http://cvsdude.com/).  As it's only me working on the code right now, I'm not using CruiseControl.net, however I expect this will change in the next couple of months and will want a full build process to kick off upon check-in.

Has anyone managed to get CruiseControl.net working with CVSDude?  My collegue Mike has this [blog post](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/01/more-on-source-repository-hosting-what.html) where someone from CVSDude said:

> "Your can use our post-commit call back facility to call a URL on your 
>   server, which passes variables relating to the last checkin (variables 
>   detailed in our specification). Your CGI script will these variables and 
>   perform whatever tasks are required i.e. updating Cruise Control, etc."

Sounds lovely.  But has anyone *actually done it* with cruisecontrol?

Answer (score 2):

I had this email back from CVSDude:

> We are currently working on a new version of our service which willeventually include CruiseControl integration.

:-/

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if you are still interested, but we have CruiseControl (the original Java-based one, not .NET, but this shouldn't matter much) working with CVSDude - it just does `svn log` every minute to check if anything changed. We plan to switch to using their API though as unfortunately `svn log` has some lag behind the realtime update.