# SVN Host + build (.net) + ftp publish - is there any hoster like this?

Tags: svn, build, ftp, publish

could you please recommend service that would host a SVN repository, do an automatic build on each commit (.net code, if that matter) and do FTP Publish at the end?

I saw Assembla is offering such thing but as part of a plan that's an overkill for my project.

Thanks in advance,

Antonin

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just implement the CI bit yourself?  [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is fantastic for this and has an easy learning curve - very simple to get up and running within a couple hours.

A quick google turns up the following links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111481/why-hasnt-anybody-started-a-hosted-continuous-integration-service

http://www.build-doctor.com/2010/02/23/continuous-integration-in-the-cloud-good-idea/

[Managed Source Control Hosting and Continuous Integration with CVSDude and CruiseControl.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395/managed-source-control-hosting-and-continuous-integration-with-cvsdude-and-cruise)

http://www.fazend.com/

https://continuityapp.com/

Comment: +1 love Hudson, fantastically easy to configure, and has great features like "rollback to last version" -damn good idea.

Comment: Agreed, setting up one of the existing CI packages is the way to go - it's the only way to get a moderately complex project configured exactly the way you want it. A hosted solution would simply have too many options.

Comment: As much as I agree that building your own CI is the best way to go, it's hard to do in my case. I only have one production box on the internet and I certainly do not want CI on such box. Also in my case, I do have a UX engineer that is really good with UX skills but have no idea how to run ASP.NET app on his box so what I really need is some way where he will update source code, commit change and within reasonable time he will see result of his work by browsing to semi-public web site. I realize this is not ideal setup but way much easier than setting local ASP.NET dev env on UX guy's box.

Comment: @Antonin - You do not need the CI server on the internet - it merely needs access to pull from SVN and to ftp up to your server(s).  A cheap desktop and a KVM switcher will cost all of $300 and you have a running CI server for your builds.

Answer (score 0):

At Codesion we have FTP deployment, along with SSH, rsync, svnsync with pre-defined targets to Joyent, S3, and AppEngine directly from your SVN repo. It won't compile the code first however, only "export" from your repo.

Check it out and see if its what you want, http://codesion.com/screenshots/publisher.html